# How to create app that can add more items later to app by developer

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to develop a movie app.. Then How can i add movies to that app through internet.

For example:  a App that has few movies, but i want to add another movies to the app (later), so the app's user don't want to update current app from windows phone store. Just updating from the app itself by the internet.

Please give me the idea.

Windows phone 8.1 (WinRT)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very, very broad question, but the general idea is this:

Occasionally, the app contacts a web-service (see: ASP.NET WebAPI for instance) which allows it to check if there is a newer version of the database available. If so, it downloads the latest version.

An alternative approach is to always have the app query the web-service and not store it itself.

It depends on two things:

1. Should the data be available offline
2. How much data is present

Here is a tutorial for WebAPI: 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

And here is one for consuming it from the app: 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Please bro,
Can you explain..
I will be pleasured if explained..

Answer (score 0):

In WinRT I would use [StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) to store the movies in `movies.xml` and [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to read the movies and [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) to download new XML file from a movies website and check for updates if available and replace the old XML file.